# How to save stock taking by name product - update quantity by name product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento-2.2.5

I wrote update quantity product by SKU, but I also want to update quantity product by name. Only update by SKU or name. Look my form <3

My form

[image]

My controller

```
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $sku = $data['sku'];
    $qty = $data['qty'];
    try {
        $productId = $this->product->getIdBySku($sku);
        $product = $this->product->load($productId);
        $stockItem = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($product->getSku());
        $stockItem->setQty($qty);
        $stockItem->save();
        $response["success"] = $this->_view->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Block\Adminhtml\Ajax\Popup')
        ->setProduct($product)
        ->setQty($qty)
            ->setSku($sku)
            ->toHtml();
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($response);
        return $resultJson;
    }
    catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        $response["error"] = $this->_view->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Block\Adminhtml\Ajax\Popup')
        ->setProduct($product)
        ->setQty($qty)
            ->setSku($sku)
            ->toHtml();
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($response);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

Please Help Me!

**UPDATE**

I saved data by SKU and name <3. but my popup not show. 
I want to show if the popup is successful, fail to show the error popup

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams(); // lấy dữ liệu
    $attr = $data['attr'];
    $qty = $data['qty'];
    $select = $data['select'];
    // save by name
    if ($select == 'name') {
        $filterName = $this->filterBuilder->setField('name')->setValue($attr)->create();
        $searchCriteriaBuilder = $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory->create();
        $searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters([$filterName]);
        $searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $productName = $product->getName();
            $productSku = $product->getSku();
            $productId = $this->product->getIdBySku($productSku);
            $product = $this->product->load($productId);
            $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($product->getSku());
            if($productName == $attr){
                $stockItem->setQty($qty);
                $stockItem->save();
                $response["success"] = $this->_view->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Block\Adminhtml\Ajax\Popup')
                ->setProduct($product)
                ->setQty($qty)
                    ->setAttr($attr)
                    ->toHtml();
                $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
                $resultJson->setData($response);
                return $resultJson;
            }else{
                $response["error"] = $this->_view->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Block\Adminhtml\Ajax\Popup')
                ->setProduct($product)
                ->setQty($qty)
                    ->setSku($attr)
                    ->toHtml();
                $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
                $resultJson->setData($response);
                return $resultJson;
            }
        }
        // save by sku
    } else if ($select == 'sku') {
        $filterSku = $this->filterBuilder->setField('sku')->setValue($attr)->create();
        $searchCriteriaBuilder = $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory->create();
        $searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters([$filterSku]);
        $searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $productSku = $product->getSku();
            $productId = $this->product->getIdBySku($productSku);
            $product = $this->product->load($productId);
            $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($product->getSku());
            $stockItem->setQty($qty);
            $stockItem->save();
            $response["error"] = $this->_view->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Block\Adminhtml\Ajax\Popup')
            ->setProduct($product)
            ->setQty($qty)
                ->setAttr($attr)
                ->toHtml();
            $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $resultJson->setData($response);
            return $resultJson;
        }
    }
```

My js file

```
require(['jquery','jquery/ui'],function($){
$("#button-unique-identifier-here").click(function(e){
    // lấy dữ liệu
    var attr = $("input[name$='general[attr]']").val();
    var stocktaking = $("input[name$='general[stocktaking]']").val();
    var select = $("select[name$='general[formats]']").val();
    if (select == "sku" || select == "name"){
        try{
            // stocktaking là chữ hoặc nhỏ hơn 1
            if (isNaN(stocktaking) || stocktaking < 1) {
                alert("StockTaking Isn't Number, Please Try Again")
                return false;
            } else {
                if (attr && stocktaking) {
                    // chạy qua controller
                    url = window.validateUrl;
                    // ajax
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type : 'post',
                        data: {attr: attr,qty: stocktaking,select:select},
                        showLoader: true,
                        success: function(data) {
                            if (data.popupValidate) {
                                //popup success
                                var popup = $('<div class="themecafe-free-popup"/>').html(data.popupValidate).modal({
                                    modalClass: 'changelog',
                                    buttons: [{

                                        text: 'Close',
                                        click: function () {
                                            this.closeModal();
                                        }
                                    },{
                                        text: 'Save',
                                        click: function () {
                                            this.closeModal();
                                            jQuery.ajax({
                                                class:'save',
                                                url: window.saveUrl,
                                                dataType: 'json',
                                                type : 'post',
                                                data: {attr: attr,qty: stocktaking,select:select},
                                                showLoader: true,
                                                success: function(data) {
                                                    console.log(data);

                                                    if (data.success) {
                                                        //popup success
                                                        var popup = $('<div class="themecafe-free-popup"/>').html(data.success).modal({
                                                            modalClass: 'changelog',
                                                            buttons: [{
                                                                text: 'Close',
                                                                click: function () {
                                                                    this.closeModal();
                                                                }
                                                            }]
                                                        });
                                                        popup.modal('openModal');
                                                        //end popup success
                                                        //popup error
                                                    } else if (data.error) {
                                                        var popup = $('<div class="themecafe-free-popup"/>').html(data.error).modal({
                                                            modalClass: 'changelog',
                                                            buttons: [{
                                                                text: 'Close',
                                                                click: function () {
                                                                    this.closeModal();
                                                                }
                                                            }]
                                                        });
                                                        popup.modal('openModal');
                                                        //end popup error
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            });
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }]
                                });
                                popup.modal('openModal');
                                //end popup success
                            }else if (data.error) {
                                var popup = $('<div class="themecafe-free-popup"/>').html(data.error).modal({
                                    modalClass: 'changelog',
                                    buttons: [{
                                        text: 'Close',
                                        click: function () {
                                            this.closeModal();
                                        }
                                    }]
                                });
                                popup.modal('openModal');
                                //end popup error
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    // Nếu không có sku và stocktaking
                    if(!attr && !stocktaking){
                        alert("Please Enter SKU And STOCKTAKING")
                    }
                    // Nếu không có sku
                    else if(!attr){
                        alert("Please Enter SKU");
                    }
                    // Nếu không có stocktaking
                    else if(!stocktaking){
                        alert("Please Enter STOCKTAKING");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch{
            alert("Please Try Again !!!");
        }
    }
})
```

});

My popupValidate.phtml open before saving data

[image]

Popup After save data

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way:

Add the following code snippet on top:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
```

Then DI:

```
public function __construct(
    ProductRepository $productRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory,
    FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory = $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
    $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
}
```

Now:

```
if ( value == sku) {
    $filter = $this->filterBuilder->setField('sku')->setValue('24-MB01')->create();
}

if (value == name ) {
    $filter = $this->filterBuilder->setField('name')->setValue('Strive Shoulder Pack')->create();
}
/** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder */
$searchCriteriaBuilder = $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory->create();
$searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters([$filter]);
$searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
$products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    error_log($product->getId());
}
```

You can merge your modification inside products loop.

Comment: thanks Sohel Rana, but i want update by only sku or name, user enter text and qty, click save -> if value = name -> update by name, if value = sku -> update by sku, look my form

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: thanks you, how to use 
ProductRepository
SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory
FilterBuilder

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: When searching by name -> $product->getId() show. When searching by sku -> $product->getId() not show. Check updated question

Comment: Your if condition not correct. Check that. Will first condition always true

Comment: I successfully edited, but did not show the popup validate, check the updated question

Comment: You should add your qty update code inside products loop 'foreach ($products as $product) {'

Comment: i saved data by sku and name <3 . but my popup not show . Check updated question

Answer (score 0):

> You need to Just load product

```
$pro->setStockData(['qty' => Product_QTY, 'is_in_stock' => true]);
$pro->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => Product_QTY, 'is_in_stock' => true]);
$pro->save();
```